# Django url patterns - how to make slug url work for multiple views

Tags: django

I see a url patterns in some websites which shows the same pattern for different objects like categories and products.

For example, when you go to tablet cases and sony camera you see the same pattern like `www.website/tablet-cases` and `www.website/sony-camera`.
How is it possible to do that in Django without getting an error as below.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/tablet-cases/
Raised by:  Product.views.category_detail_view
```

I mean, how can I use the same pattern for both categories and products as below:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_detail'),
```

Comment: i'm not sure about the question: why not add an extra namespace to avoid possible collisions (and problems)? like: `/product/your-slug` and `/category/category-slug`. also: what char is this `’`?

Answer (score 2):

Django matches the first regex, in this case the `product_detail` view. By default, Django doesn't have a way to try each url in turn, so the category view will never be called with your current urls.

The easiest fix is to namespace your urls. This might be a good idea - at the moment, you'll have problems if you ever have a category and a product with the same slug.

```
url(r'^products/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
url(r'^categories/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_detail'),
```

Another option is to create a single view, say `product_or_category`. In that, you could test to see whether the slug matches a category or slug, and continue. This will work, but you might have a bit of duplicated code, and it might not seem as as elegant as the two class based views you currently have.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', product_or_category, name='product_or_category'),
```

Finally, there's a project [django-multiurl](https://github.com/raiderrobert/django-multiurl) that appears to do what you want. I have never used it, so I can't make any claims for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems like django-multiple url worked for now. I'll keep trying.